# Eager loading with constraint on the eager loaded field

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a DB with employees:

```
id
name
manager_id
```

foreign key is manager id and pointing at id of the same table employees.

I would like to get the list of employees but only where the manager name is called 'MANAGER'.

I tried this but it is not working:

```
$employee_list = Employee::with(['manager' => function($query){
            $query->where('name', 'MANAGER');
        }]);
```

I guess it is not working because it is constraining the function that will replace the ids with the name.

How can I constrain on the whole result so that I take only the records where the manager_id points to the record with name = 'MANAGER'?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you defined relation the right way, to get results you have to use `get` function so it should be:

```
$employee_list = Employee::whereHas(['manager' => function($query){
            $query->where('name', 'MANAGER');
        }])->get();
```

to get any results from database.

Comment: I know that, I m asking how I can get all the results where manager_id has a name different than 'MANAGER'. I could use a join clause but I was wondering if this was possible using the with statement only. The command I have written where you only added ->get() will give me all the records and show me the manager name only when the manager name is 'MANAGER' which is not what I want, I want to have the where to apply on the whole result, not only on the link to the managers.

Comment: @Richard What you want is probably using `whereHas` function as in my edited answer. If it's not that, sorry I cannot help you because it's not clear what exactly you want.